# Output mixed Hebrew & English to Excel starting on left, uniformly

Tags: java, excel, right-to-left

I have a list of object Strings with some Hebrew and English mixed.  The Sentence always starts with Hebrew.  My GOAL output is:

```
אדר: Mon, 40 minutes and 11 חלקים after 12:00 PM
ניסן: Wed, 24 minutes and 12 חלקים after 1:00 AM
אייר: Thu, 8 minutes and 13 חלקים after 2:00 PM
סיון: ‎שבת‎, 52 minutes and 14 חלקים after 2:00 AM
```

Current output:

[image: Starting printing from after with Hebrew showing at end]

I've tried interject the left to right bytes such as `"\u202E" + "שבת" + "\u202D"` but I can't find a combination of code that makes this uniformly work.

At a minimum if I print the cell starting with an English character it starts in the right place, but the Hebrew after the colon starts the same issue:

[image: Starts correctly but 4th object messed up]

Here is some Sample Java code to generate the above

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TestHebrew {

    int rowNumber = 1;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFRow row;

    @Test
    public void TestHebrewEnglishInterlace() throws IOException {
        List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(new MyObject("אדר", "Mon, 40 minutes and 11 חלקים after 12:00 PM"));
        objects.add(new MyObject("ניסן", "Wed, 24 minutes and 12 חלקים after 1:00 AM"));
        objects.add(new MyObject("אייר", "Thu, 8 minutes and 13 חלקים after 2:00 PM"));
        objects.add(new MyObject("סיון", "Sat, 52 minutes and 14 חלקים after 2:00 AM"));

        objects.get(3).description = objects.get(3).description.replace("Sat", "שבת");


        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            sheet = workbook.createSheet("TestSheet");
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);

            XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style.setWrapText(true);
            style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
            for (MyObject o : objects) {
                addCellAndNextRow(style, o.month + ":" + "" + o.description);
            }

            addCellAndNextRow(style, "");
            addCellAndNextRow(style, "Same values but appending English first");
            addCellAndNextRow(style, "");

            for (MyObject o : objects) {
                addCellAndNextRow(style, "a " + o.month + ": " + "" + o.description);
            }

            IntStream.range(0, 1).forEach(i -> sheet.autoSizeColumn(i));

            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().toPath().resolve("output.xlsx").toFile())) {
                workbook.write(out);
            }
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().toPath().resolve("output.xlsx").toFile());

        }
    }

    private void addCellAndNextRow(XSSFCellStyle style, String value) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        row = sheet.createRow(++rowNumber);
    }

    static class MyObject {
        String month;
        String description;

        public MyObject(String month, String description) {
            this.month = month;
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice sample code 10/10 ;)

Comment: Hey at least that version was bug-free :)